# <picture> only showing the default <img> in Safari and ignoring the <source> elements

Tags: html, image, safari

It's been some weeks that I have the problem and I cant find a fix!

```
HTML
<picture>
      <source
        media="screen and (min-width: 31.25em) and (max-width: 50em)"
        srcset="/img/home-bg-tablet.png"
        type="image/png"
      />
      <source
        media="screen and (min-width: 50em) and (max-width: 100em)"
        srcset="/img/home-bg-desk.png"
        type="image/png"
      />
      <source
        media="screen and (min-width: 100em)"
        srcset="/img/home-bg-large.png"
        type="image/png"
      />
      <img
        src="/img/home-bg-mobile.png"
        alt="Artisan travaillant le bois"
      />
</picture>
```

This picture element is showing the correct source element in Chrome and Firefox, but only using the img default element in Safari for all screen sizes. I don't understand why.

It doesn't look like there is a compatibility problem with Safari so I must do something wrong.

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to bypass the problem by replacing the picture element and its srcset attributes by media queries in javascript:

```js
window.onresize = () => {
    const imgEl = document.getElementById("home-bg-img");

    if (window.matchMedia("screen and (max-width: 31.25em)").matches) {
        imgEl.src = "/img/home-bg-mobile.png";
    } else if (window.matchMedia("screen and (min-width: 31.25em) and (max-width: 50em)").matches) {
        imgEl.src = "/img/home-bg-tablet.png";
    } else if (window.matchMedia("screen and (min-width: 50em) and (max-width: 100em)").matches) {
        imgEl.src = "/img/home-bg-desk.png";
    } else {
        imgEl.src = "/img/home-bg-large.png";
    }
};
```